# Change href to tel: + number (user defined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, href

I'm trying to write a script where users can type a phone number and store it in the input (which works in this demo: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/iphone-number-pad) and then update href="" = "tel:" + that-same-value. So for example the if the user types 600 999 999 the href is updated to href="tel:600 999 999" and the user can then click the the button and make a call.

I've been beating myself up trying to figure this out. It seemed really simple because I'm not even trying to use restrict the phone number to 6-7 characters long.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
     // Get number
     $('.num').click(function() {
       var num = $(this);
       var text = $.trim(num.find('.txt').clone().children().remove().end().text());
       var telNumber = $('#telNumber');
       $(telNumber).val(telNumber.val() + text);
       $('#call-this').href = "tel:" + $(telNumber).val(telNumber.val() + text)

       console.log(text);
       console.log(telNumber);
     });
     // add number to href
     var call = $(#call - this).attr('target')
       // Other stuff I've tired
       //   $('#call-this').click(
       //   $('#call-this').href="tel:" + $(telNumber).val(telNumber.val() + text)
       //    var call = $('#call-this');
       //    $('#call-this').href=  "tel:" + telNumber;
       //    console.log(call);
       // });

   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="tel" name="name" id="telNumber" class="form-control tel" value="" />
<div class="num">
  <div class="txt">0</div>
</div>
<div class="num">
  <div class="txt">1</div>
</div>
<div class="num">
  <div class="txt">2</div>
</div>

<div class="num">
  <div class="txt">3</div>
</div>
<div class="num">
  <div class="txt">4</div>
</div>
<div class="num">
  <div class="txt">5</div>
</div>

<div class="num">
  <div class="txt">6</div>
</div>
<div class="num">
  <div class="txt">7</div>
</div>
<div class="num">
  <div class="txt">8</div>
</div>
<div class="num">
  <div class="txt">9</div>
</div>
<button class="expand">
  <a href="#" id="call-this" style="color:black;">Call</a>
</button>
```

Comment: Why all the `>` prefixes?

Comment: Can you give a fiddle?

Comment: @Barmar the op is new to SO, question formatting takes some getting used to ^^

Comment: The line beginning with `var call` is invalid Javascript syntax.

Comment: Yeah I am brand new to overstack and thank you very much for all the replies I didn't expect that and yeah formatting is weird. Also didn't know you could post executable (which is cool)...

I @void here is plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/wzDVAv?p=preview
. It's in phone-call.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function can actually be simplified into this — the reason is that you don't need to actually transverse all the way to the `.txt` element if it is the one and only child of `.num` and that it only contains the number of interest.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.num').click(function () {
        // Append trimmed number to current value
        $(telNumber).val($(telNumber).val() + $(this).text().trim());

        // Update href attribute on #call-this
        $('#call-this').attr('href', 'tel:'+$(telNumber).val());
    });
});
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/jwqL4o8w/3

---

In fact, a better choice would be to store the number in the HTML5 `data-` attribute, so you can freely change the innerHTML of the `.txt` element without having to worry about issues:

```
<div class="num" data-num="0">
    <div class="txt">0</div>
</div>
```

Then for your JS, just use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.num').click(function () {
        // Append trimmed number to current value
        $(telNumber).val($(telNumber).val() + $(this).data('num'));

        // Update href attribute on #call-this
        $('#call-this').attr('href', 'tel:'+$(telNumber).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: @Terry Thanks a lot. Functionally that works like I described. The only problem is that it also grabs the text in <span>. Which is fine because worst case I can just order the html and restyle the css. 

Check out the plunker to see what I mean:
http://plnkr.co/edit/wzDVAv?p=preview

Comment: Then use this line instead: `$(telNumber).val($(telNumber).val() + $(this).find('.txt').children().remove().end().text().trim());`. However, please do consider storing your numbers in HTML5 attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I think where you have

```
$('#call-this').href="tel:" + $(telNumber).val(telNumber.val() + text)
```

It should be

```
$('#call-this').attr("href", "tel:" + telNumber.val());
```

**edit** I just caught the double `val()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this, i have simplified the solution.

```js
   $("#telNumber").on("blur", function() {
     $("#call-this").prop("href", "tel:" + $(this).val());
     alert($("#call-this").prop("href"));
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="tel" name="name" id="telNumber" class="form-control tel" value="" />
<button class="expand">
  <a href="#" id="call-this" style="color:black;">Call</a>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link a button your HTML code should look like this:

```
<input type="tel" name="name" id="telNumber" class="form-control tel" value="" />
<div class="num">
    <div class="txt">0</div>
</div>
<div class="num">
    <div class="txt">1</div>
</div>
<div class="num">
    <div class="txt">2</div>
</div>
<div class="num">
    <div class="txt">3</div>
</div>
<div class="num">
    <div class="txt">4</div>
</div>
<div class="num">
    <div class="txt">5</div>
</div>
<div class="num">
    <div class="txt">6</div>
</div>
<div class="num">
    <div class="txt">7</div>
</div>
<div class="num">
    <div class="txt">8</div>
</div>
<div class="num">
    <div class="txt">9</div>
</div>
<form action="#">
    <input type="submit" value="Call" />
</form>
```

and script will be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.txt').on('click', function () {
        $("#telNumber").val($("#telNumber").val() + $(this).text());
        $("form").attr('action', "tel:" + $("#telNumber").val());
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c1c0p04z/3/)